# Is it valid to call QJSEngine::newQObject() in a C++ function called by a script?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qjsengine

Consider this example:

`ObjectCreator` is set as global property via `QJSEngine`:

```cpp
// ObjectCreator is exposed to engine_ env as global property
class ObjectCreator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ObjectCreator(QJSEngine * engine, QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), engine_(engine) {}
    
    // Called from script env
    Q_INVOKABLE QJSValue createObject();

private:
    
    // engine_ is not owned
    QJSEngine * engine_ = nullptr;
};

class SomeObj : public QObject
{
    // ...
};

QJSValue ObjectCreator::createObject()
{
    // No parent due to JavaScriptOwnership
    return engine_->newQObject(new SomeObj());
}
```

JavaScript (evaluated in `engine_` from previous snippet):

```js
function f
{
        // objectCreator is a global property of engine_
        const someObj = objectCreator.createObj();
}
```

Reading the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#newQObject) I couldn't find an answer to this question:

Is it valid to call `engine_->newQObject()` in a C++ function that is invoked via a JavaScript-script that is evaluated by `engine_`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally fine for a C++ to call a `QJSEngine::newQObject()` when called from a script.

The issue you may have is that `const` is not supported by ECMAScript 5, which is QJSEngine's version (see the explanation at [QTBUG-69408](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69408?focusedCommentId=411798&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-411798)). Replace it with `var` and it should work (though obviously it's not a constant).

Comment: thanks for taking the time!  Would you mind pointing me to the respective section in the documentation or source code that covers this (if any)?

Comment: I don't really understand your doubt `QJSEngine::newQObject()` is a C++ method, and thus can be invoked by any C++ code. Moreover, if the C++ code is exposed to scripts (via `Q_INVOKABLE`, for instance), it's still C++ code, and thus it is completely valid to invoke `newQObject()`

There won't be speficic documentation telling that you can create a C++ object from a Javascript invocation because it is follows from the basic premises listed above.

Note that you can even call `engine_->newQObject()` from another script object (e.g., `engine_2`)

Comment: Basically what happens is calling a function of an instance of `QJSEngine` while another function call of this very same instance has not yet returned.  Our concern is that this might trigger undefined behavior.